# Ajax infinite scrolling not loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So in my index.php file i have this:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(window).scroll(function() {
           var load = 0;
           if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
               load++;
               $.POST("scripts/myload.php",{load:load},function(data){
                 $.('photoclass').append(data);
               })
           }
        });
      </script>
```

and in my "myload.php" file i have this

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM photo LIMIT ".$load.",5");
while($photo = $query->fetch()){
  echo '<center><h1 class="ptitle">'.$photo['PhotoTitle'].'</h1></center>';
  echo '<center><img src="UserPhotos/'.$photo['Photo'].'"></center>';
}
```

The problem is that it won't load in my index file the rest... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change your jquery code.

`$.('photoclass').append(data);` to

`$('.photoclass').append(data);` or `$('#photoclass').append(data);`

putting "." or "#" depends on class or id.

for example :

`<div class="photoclass"> </div>`then use `$('.photoclass').append(data);` otherwise `$('#photoclass').append(data);`

and in your php file make sure you are saving post value to variable.

like this `$load=$_POST['load']`

Comment: I changed it to "$('.photoclass').append(data);" and i have the $load = $_POST['load'] in my other file, but i still does not work